# What does "dying over" mean?

Tags: meaning

I was watching [this short YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dXYlVkvdvI).

One of the viewer commented this:

> This girl kicks ass!  I'm still dying over "You're a bad dog!"

I want to know what does "dying over" mean here? Can't find it in the dictionary.

Comment: To die over something can mean: to be really surprised by something, usually,  in a good way. At least, in AmE colloquial speech. Here, the speaker is dying over what someone else said.

Comment: Could be something like 'still laughing'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, *over* means *about*, *die* - *laugh*.

> You use *[over](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/over)* to indicate what a disagreement or feeling relates to or is caused by.

They were laughing (uncontrollably/wholeheartedly/for a long time) at the reproaching remark she shouted.

Similarly, you can [die laughing](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/die-laughing).

Comment: I annoyed a colleague who told me she 'literally died laughing' by saying 'What, are you a ghost?'.